# How do I finish proving that this set does not have a lower bound?

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I am having some troubles on a real analysis exercise where I had to prove that this set has no lower bound. Here's the problem and how I tackled the problem but I don't know what to do next to prove the statement. Any help?

Show that the set $A=\left\{\frac{5x-2}{x}\mid\ x\in\mathbb{R}_+\right\}$ has no lower bound

Proof:

BWOC let's assume that the set A has a lower bound. That means that there
exists a real number m such that $m\le\frac{5x-2}{x}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$
We can assume $m\lt 5$ because the upper bound of the set A is 5 (I checked this while proving the upper bound of this set)

(Scratch work:
$m\le\frac{5x-2}{x}$

$\Leftrightarrow\ x\le\frac{5x-2}{m}=\frac{5}{m}x-\frac{2}{m}$

$\Leftrightarrow\ x-\frac{5}{m}x=x\left(1-\frac{5}{m}\right)\le-\frac{2}{m}$

$\Leftrightarrow\ x\le-\frac{2}{m}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{5}{m}}=-\frac{2}{m-5}$

Here we get the idea to choose a number x as $-\frac{2}{m-5}$
Scratch work ends)

Let's choose x as $x=-\frac{2}{m-5}$

Now substituting that into $\frac{5x-2}{x}$ we get
$\frac{5\left(-\frac{2}{m-5}\right)-2}{-\frac{2}{m-5}}=\frac{-\frac{10}{m-5}-2}{-\frac{2}{m-5}}=\frac{\frac{10}{m-5}+2}{\frac{2}{m-5}}=\frac{\frac{10}{m-5}+\frac{2\left(m-5\right)}{m-5}}{\frac{2}{m-5}}
=\frac{\frac{10+2\left(m-5\right)}{m-5}}{\frac{2}{m-5}}=\frac{10+2\left(m-5\right)}{2}=5+m-5=m$

So $\frac{5x-2}{x}=m$

What am I supposed to do with the information that that expression is equal to m?

How do I complete my proof by contradiction?

Comment: You are making the contrapositive assumption that $m$ is a lower bound. One way of running into a contradiction would be to exhibit a real number $x$ such that $(5x-2)/x$ is strictly less than $m$. Can you find an $x$ such that the ratio takes, for example, the value $m-1$? Or, can you plug in $m-1$ into your formula instead of $m$?

Comment: Your first step is wrong because you don't know that $m>0$. Dividing an inequality by a  negative number reverses the inequality.

Comment: Mind you, it may be simpler to plot $(5x-2)/x$ and see what happens. You still need to practice rigor, but the plot tells the real story.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{5x-2}x=5-\frac2x.$$

Comment: Not $\frac {5x-2}x = 5 - \frac x2$. That might be easier to use.  But I'd use a direct proof.  If you can show that for any $M$ there will exist an $\frac{5x-2}x < M$ you are done.

Comment: ... and if we assume $M < 0$ (because ... why not?) then $\frac {5x-2}x=5-\frac 2x < M \iff -\frac 2x < M -5\iff \frac 2x > 5-M$ and if we assume $x$ is possitive but really really small... well, this is easy to solve.... So we are done.  No negative number can be a lower bound, and if a negative number can't be a lower bound no positive or $0$ number can be either.

Comment: The limit in 0 is -\infty